# Description of topological spaces with lifting property

Tags: algebraic-topology

We say that topological space $L$ has **lifting property** if for any covering $\tilde{X} \xrightarrow{\pi} X$ and any map $L \xrightarrow{f} X$ we can lift $f$ to $L \xrightarrow{\tilde{f}} \tilde X,$ such that $\pi \circ \tilde{f} = f.$

How can we describe such good spaces (good = have lifting property)?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $L$ has your "lifting property" and is nice enough to have a universal cover $p:\tilde{L}\to L$ ([this happens when $L$ is connected, locally path-connected and semi-locally simply connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Universal_covers)).

Then you get a lift of $\mathrm{id}:L\to L$ to a map $\widetilde{\mathrm{id}}:L\to \tilde{L}$ such that $p\circ\widetilde{\mathrm{id}}=\mathrm{id}$. Since $\pi_1(\tilde{L})=0$, this forces the map on fundamental groups induced by $\mathrm{id}:L\to L$ to be the trivial map, which means $\pi_1(L)=0$.

This is also sufficient, by the general lifting property of coverings ([see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Lifting_properties), or [Proposition 1.33 in Hatcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeuZb.png)).

Thus, we can conclude that
$$L\text{ has your  “lifting property” (and has a universal cover) }\iff \pi_1(L)=0$$

Comment: OK. And can I find "bad" counterexample when it's not so nice?

Comment: I mean counterexample to proposition: $L$ has  "lifting property" but hasn't universal cover.